# Map not loading after building Quake 2 from source

Tags: quake2

I'm a big fan of the game `Quake 2`. Recently I've decided to spend some of my free time for digging into the `Quake 2` source code. There are 2 versions of the full game code, `3.19` and `3.21` (including the `game exe` as well as the `game dll`).

As regards to the Q2 Mission Packs, the source files for both The Reckoning and Ground Zero are for version 3.20 as the filename suggests (`xatrixsrc320.exe` and `roguesrc320.exe`)

I've compiled the 3.21 exe and 3.20 xatrix dll and when I run quake2 +set game xatrix I'm getting the following message in the game console:

> ... Dropped frame 21 > 20 ...

...and the map/game isn't loading.

How do I allow the map/game to be loaded?

Comment: To be honest, it looks like what you need is a complete tutorial on how to get from point A to point B; even if a user here manages to compile the game and load the map and start the game, it does not mean that the hurdles you have will be the same as the ones others have.